# I'm working on model bias monitoring in sagemaker, Is it possible to run the monitoring job manually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I've done the baseline creation part where I'm getting *analysis_config.json* file.
So next step is doing the monitoring job part, Is it possible to run  monitoring job manually for **Monitor Bias Drift** and the next step **Feature Attribution Drift** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can run the model monitoring job manually by configuring the process job with appropriate parameters. Please find an example in the reference [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-mlops-workshop/blob/main/labs/05_model_monitor/monitoringjob_utils.py)

Comment: What parameters should be modified. As above mentioned in my problem. I'm getting _analysis_config.json_ file. According to the link that you've shared it takes two parameters as input one is stat and other is constraint, I tried that but I'm not sure about the _env_ for _analaysis_config.json_ file.